# Vaadin 8.14.3 on Eclipse 2023-03 now gets Vaadin plugin and Maven exceptions

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, vaadin8

I have been using the same setup for some time now without any issues, but then I all of a sudden got various errors trying to do a Maven Clean Build on my project.

Here are some screen shots of expired certs and such that may help to the root issue we are facing.

[image: Vaadin expired certMaven error]

I was simply doing a Maven Clean Build like before in Eclipse.

Comment: Maven->Update Project results in error dialog "An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project"
 'org.apache.m2e.core.project.MavenProject org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.ProjectConfigurationRequest.getMavenProject()'

Comment: Noted that the vaadin eclipse plugin is 4.1.7, and the prior that seemed to work was 4.1.6. Is it possible to get the 4.1.6 version again to try to see if that resolves the issue?